# Hibernate cannot see OJDBC6 driver

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I have a problem in my project, I try to configurate hibernate without using hibernate.cfg.xml file, I do it this way:

```
  private SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        System.out.println(hostname);
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new Configuration()
                .addAnnotatedClass(DBUser.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(DBTrustee.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(DBTrusteeUser.class)
                .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
                .setProperty("connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+hostname)
                .setProperty("connection.username", username)
                .setProperty("connection.password", password)
                .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect")
                .setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "apps")
                .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

And it cannot see my OJDBC6 driver which is in my build path, It was seen when I used hibernate.cfg.xml file but when i try to avoid using file I am getting this:

> WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
>   lut 12, 2016 7:26:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
>   WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
>   lut 12, 2016 7:26:06 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect

What am I doing wrong ? I've tried using both of the jdbc driver classes:
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
and
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

and still no luck :(

Comment: provider it is no the same as the driver, need to check but driver is not the problem is the provider

Comment: So here was my previous attempt using an xml file:  `<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">apps</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>`
And it worked fine... :( without provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Changing this:

```
.setProperty("connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+hostname)
.setProperty("connection.username", username)
.setProperty("connection.password", password)
```

To this:

```
.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+hostname)
.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username)
.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password)
```

Solved the problem. Maybe this will help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My last try, using hibernate 5, taking from the aPI and manual it said.

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties() // configures settings from Configuration object
            .build();
    try {
        sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
        // so destroy it manually.
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
    }
```

[This](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/quickstart/html/) is the quick start for hibernate 5 , instead of call configure alone, you need to pass the configuration object that you have created with your properties.

Comment: First of all, as far as I've read configure() method looks for hibernate.cfg.xml file and it does because when trying to execute it, it throws an exception. Secondly, the ServiceRegistry and ServiceRegistryBuilder as far what I've read are deprecated - there is no such class ServiceRegistryBuilder in newest hibernate, I am using this: `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Made an update in my response using the javadoc hibernat5 http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/

Comment: It still doesnt work, the output in console is the same, it cant find the ojdbc6 driver, here is full class: [link](http://pastebin.com/FDuF9V7c) I try to run the setUp method in a constructor of HibernateUtil Class and then getSessionFactory with getter. I believe I did it as you said...

Comment: Are you sure the driver is in the classpaht, or lib folder ? Try to run some test with Class.forName(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();, within the same class to see if the drivers is within the class path, if you get ClassNotFoundException, we are in troubles, the driver will be in the runtime classpath which sometimes is not the same as the compilation classpath

Comment: I am sure because it worked as stated before in the xml which part I posted before. I am very thankful for your help. I may even invite your for a teamviewer session if you want to and see for yourself. EDIT: Yes I did try Class.forName(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance(); in the same class and it did not threw an exception, do you have an idea what can be trouble ?